# Launching a separate/stand-alone application from a bash script

Tags: linux, shell-script

I'd like to launch an executable file(application) from a bash script, exit the script, close the terminal and let the application run by itself. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

`NOHUP` is indeed the 'standard' solution. But I usually use

```
screen -s somecommand -S somename -d -m
```

This will start `somecommand` in  session named `somename` in the background.
The session will stop automatically once the command ends.

Using screen has (among other things) the advantage that you can:

- Run `screen -r somename` to place the command in the foreground
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to place it back in the background